# Upload Excel Reports to Access through VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, automation

**What?**

I receive reports in Excel in three different formats depending on asset type. I am trying to create a database in access where I can add and filter based on certain criteria.

**So Far..**

I am thinking I should make a master Excel document where I can filter the data that I need through a macro, but wondering if there is any way to automatically upload these reports to access as I receive them. It needs to be able to take certain criteria from two separate sheets within a workbook, and append that data to the existing table in access. Is this possible or is there an easier way I am not thinking of?

Any input would be greatly appreicated it.

Comment: why you use macros, only make a consolidated excel file & import it into access.

Comment: why use vba, Access can directly run SQL on Excel workbooks including append.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive these reports on a regular basis (let us say once per month) then you should really consider of linking these excel files as external data to access database instead of straight importing the data from them into database.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958#__link_to_data

This way you only need to replace the old excel files with the new ones to get be able to access to the new data.

NOTE: When you replace the old excel files with the new ones the data from old excel files will no longer be available to the database.
So if you need to preserve that data make sure your database have a special copy query with which you can copy data from the linked table to existing data table in access database.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-records-to-a-table-by-using-an-append-query-98a5bd66-2190-4243-9638-8ef649cf3596